# Continuity of complex functions with sequences

Tags: complex-analysis

In real functions, a function $f$ is continuous in $c$, if for every sequence $x_n \rightarrow c$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$.

Does this condition hold as well for complex variable function?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Yes, you just have more complex (ha ha) possibilities for the way that sequences can converge to a given point.

Comment: Yes, the theorem $$\left(\forall c\in X,\,\forall x_n\to c,\, f(x_n)\to f(c)\right)\implies f\text{ continuous}$$ actually holds whenever $X$ is a [first-countable topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space).